# how to create an object logic via thf

Tags: isabelle

How can I create an object logic in Isabelle via thf?

What I have found about creating an object logic in the documentation was

```
2.3 Example: First-Order Logic
```

in the Isabelle/Isar reference manual.

What else should I read on object logics and using thf in particular?

THF is typed higher-order form as in the paper [here](http://www.ags.uni-sb.de/~chris/papers/C25.pdf)

Comment: Please elaborate: What is thf?

Comment: I do not quite get your goal. Could you please clarify?

Comment: The traditional way to create an object logic is to write encoding in Pure. I have heard that now this is possible using THF. The question is: how?

Comment: I have never heard about this. You might want to talk to Jasmin Blanchette (Sledgehammer interacts with TPTP formats). If I remember correctly, he has some code to import theories in certain TPTP formats into Isabelle/HOL (not as a separate object logic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: currently, you can't.

There is no facility in Isabelle to define an object logic only via THF. Object logics are still defined building on Pure as in the example you cite.